# How can I upgrade the openGL version on a compute engine VM on GCP?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, windows-server-2016, opengl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

GCP Compute Engine Machine info
 - Windows server 2016
 - Xeon (R) 2Ghz 8 cores
 - RAM 7.2 GB
 - 1 Nvidia Tesla T4 Virtual workstation GPU
 - Connection using RDP

I'm trying to install Blender (3d app) which needs a minimum openGL 2.1 but my compute engine has openGL 1.1

Google compute engine VM screenshot:

[image]

I've installed nvidia drivers for Tesla T4 GPU from the nvidia website as well as updated windows server 2016, still the openGL error.

Please tell me how can I update the openGl version in my compute engine VM.

P.S. If I missed any info, please let me know.

Comment: @DavidPostill GCP is not really on-topic on WebApps, either.  The tag wiki should probably be changed to reflect that.  It's just as much off-topic as something like EC2 unless the question is explicitly about the use of the web interface of the GCP as a web application.

Comment: @jonsca Fair enough.

Comment: Try to use Mesa3d, you should be able to get OpenGL running, but maybe not on the GPU.

Comment: Same problem here on Google VM Windows Server 2019. And with GPU K80, Windows Update made no improvement to OpenGL version number V1.1,